# Referenced GZipped JavaScript files not working

Tags: javascript, gzip

This platform I'm working on uses some mechanics to determine if it should do a `<script>` link to a straight up `.js` file or a `.js.gz` file, depending on browser type and version.

On the current server, everything works fine, and both `js` and `js.gz` files work, and the javascript is executed in the browser. However, transfer it all over, verbatim, to a new server, and suddenly Firefox stops using the `gz` files. It will download them (as can be seen using Firebug) but it's not executing them.

Any ideas on why the gzipped files aren't being used properly?

**Response headers From Old**

```
Date              Thu, 25 Nov 2010 17:06:32 GMT
Server            Apache
Last-Modified     Mon, 22 Nov 2010 21:31:00 GMT
Etag              "55808a3-3f1e-4ceae114"
Accept-Ranges     bytes
Content-Length    16158
Keep-Alive        timeout=15, max=100
Connection        Keep-Alive
Content-Type      application/javascript
Content-Encoding  gzip
```

**Response Headers from New**

```
Date               Thu, 25 Nov 2010 17:00:11 GMT
Server             Apache/2.2.17 (CentOS)
Last-Modified      Thu, 25 Nov 2010 16:11:00 GMT
Etag               "693c304-4178-495e2da08cd00"
Accept-Ranges      bytes
Content-Length     16760
Connection         close
Content-Type       application/x-gzip
```

I'm going to assume it's from the Content-Encoding and Type, though I've no idea how to change this.

**FIX**
Taking the answers and comments into account, I made the following changed to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, where commented (`#`) lines are what was there, uncommented is my replacement:

```
# Technically just uncommented this line
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

#AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
AddType application/javascript .gz
```

Comment: Any hint on the Content-Type that would be different on both servers?

Comment: Yes, Content-Type is probably the problem. Make sure it’s javascript on the new server als well. Also check the HTTP-response headers that gzip compression is indicated.

Comment: @Danosaure and @Kissaki, i'm pretty sure mime type doesn't matter - for historical reasons half the scripts at my work are generated w/ php and served as text/html and they work fine (Please note i am in no way responsible for any of these scripts, don't blame me!)

Comment: @Danosaure, @Kissaki Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Changed some settings in httpd.conf (will later try using a straight .htaccess file instead) but managed to change the headers sent, and got it working.

Comment: Hurray... If you post what you changed in httpd.conf, it would help others with the same trouble in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a server side setting/module - clients don't know how to handle gziped *files* however they usually know how to handle files compressed in transit as long as you tell them how you've compressed them using a `Content-Encoding` header.

basicly i think you'll find that the server isn't sending a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header on the new server, but it is on the old.

Comment: Checked the headers, played around in httpd.conf, and got it sending the right Content-Type and Content-Encoding. force-refresh the page, and everything loaded properly. Thanks for helping to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Apache, it might be possible that your former web server had [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) enabled but your current web server doesn’t. Try to enable it in your current server too (at least for that directory):

```
Options +MultiViews
```