# Why does fetching a gzipped file not work in localhost (with Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, gzip

I am utterly confused by gzipping ...

**Situation:**

1. I have a json-file with 2mb that I'd like to gzip.
2. It should work on the basic, cheap FTP server that my client has/uses
3. The file basically never changes, so I'd like to pre-gzip it and don't do it dynamically (also regarding 2.)

At first I thought I need a library like [Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako), but then I read that it is [supported natively](https://caniuse.com/sr_content-encoding-gzip) by browsers.

#### I tried it with the following example:

##### example.json

```
{
    "this-is-a": "simple-json"
}
```

##### example.json.gz (created with [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html))

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0013 abe6 5200 02a5
928c cc62 5d20 4a54 b252 502a cecc 2dc8
49d5 cd2a cecf 53e2 aa05 00f2 869a 6022
0000 00
```

##### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        fetchGzippedData('./example.json.gz')

        function fetchGzippedData(url){
            fetch(url).then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error('Error loading file')
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Result

The weird thing is it doesn't work on localhost (using [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or with [Astro preview](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/cli-reference/#astro-preview)).
It also doesn't work on my personal server, but it does work on my client's server.

So I assume it has to do with server configuration (which I have no experience with) ... but why doesn't it work in localhost?

##### Related:

- [Gzipped javascript not being served properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850546/gzipped-javascript-not-being-served-properly)
- [Referenced GZipped JavaScript files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279245/referenced-gzipped-javascript-files-not-working)

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, the "catch"-section of the code is triggered.

Comment: Well maybe log the actual error object instead of (or in addition to) your own message, that might contain a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.

**It fails because the the .gz-file's Response Header Content-Encoding is wrong or missing.**
(This information can be viewed for the respective file in the Network-tab in the browser's debug tools.)

It has to be set to `Content-Encoding` : `gzip`

Once it's correct it can fetch and parse the json-file as it wasn't gzipped.

For the static site server [serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve) I am using you can set options via a [serve.json](https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#options):
(But I also saw [similar information for Apache](https://gist.github.com/osvik/9b3ff2d87bd2d131de11))

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source" : "**/*.@(gz|gzip)",
      "headers" : [{
        "key" : "Content-Encoding",
        "value" : "gzip"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Side note:** I noticed, that if you access the .gz-file via the browser directly:

- If Content-Encoding is correct: The browser shows the file content
- If Content-Encoding is *not* correct: The browser will download the file